# More Portable Makefiles?

Tags: linux, makefile, dependency-management, portability

So, I get the basic concept and layout of a makefile, how to compile and link against libraries, etc. But, what I'm still unsure about is how to make these makefiles more portable in terms of linking against library dependencies.

Here's an example. Say, I write a C++ program on my machine, which runs Manjaro, an Arch-based linux distro, and I upload my source code to github. Now though, when person two comes along and maybe they're running Ubuntu, who's package manager might have downloaded the necessary dependencies to a different folder than my Manjaro package manager did. So now when they attempt to "make" after cloning my repo, my makefile will search for the library dependencies in a folder that exists on my operating system but does not and their's, and will ultimately fail. How do I account for different package manager's installing dependencies in different folders for people on different operating systems (not even including Windows and Mac users, which I assume would be a whole different beast)?

Comment: In linux many libraries use `pkg-config` to discover the library configuration. For more complex setups, many programs use `autoconf`.

Comment: cmake (https://cmake.org/) is also a good option.

Comment: I'll be surprised if there is "one-true answer" for this, but I agree that pkg-config and autoconf are your best hopes. Be sure to include a README.txt and maybe BUILD.txt describing what you are supplying in your package, what you know to be required dependencies, and any "best practices" you care to define for your package. Any developer worth their salt will be very grateful for that information and know how to use it avoid having to post a query to the support board. Good luck.